# Looking for the best and simple-to-setup notification handler app for Python Django

Tags: django, notifications

I'm setting up a django user platform with user notifications.

**I have the following requirements for my notifications**

1. I'd like users to have a notification feed visible on-hover the menu entry "Notifications".
2. The notification feed (in every site inheriting base.html + a menu) should show a maximum of the newest  5 unread notifications in every user site.
3. The notifications should be saved into the database as objects.

*optional:*

4. live reload via AJAX
5. send via mail + user preferences for notifications

**What I found so far:**

I looked at [the django documentation](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/notification/), but I had the feeling none of the above worked smoothly for my purpose.

1. Stream framework was way too complicated to set-up for me with a custom database.
2. django-notifications (like GitHub) was way too buggy and is maintained very slowly.
3. I like pinax-notifications, could set it up, but I don't see from the [documentation](https://github.com/pinax/pinax-notifications#documentation) how to show all notifications in my base.html template for the logged in user and also I don't see how it saves notifications to the database.
4. I also found django-pusherable, don't know if it works for notifications?

Can you give me any tips on how to set-up or any app recommendations?

Kind regards